# How to store different data structures in a list (or a different structure)?

Tags: r

I have a matrix, a vector, an integer, and another list. These values change every time. I want to store these as individual rows (or of some sort) in a data structure.

The first value would be,

```
p <- c(1, 3, 4)
q <- matrix(c(1, 2, 4, 5), nrow=2, ncol=2)
r <- 8745
```

The second value would be

```
p <- c(1, 4, 4)
q <- matrix(c(5, 5, 4, 6), nrow=2, ncol=2)
r <- 8745454
```

And the third values,

```
p <- c(2, 5, 4)
q <- matrix(c(1, 3, 3, 6), nrow=2, ncol=2)
r <- 87
```

and so on

The ideal output is,

```
> Map(rbind, something) #if I do rbind
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    4
[2,]    1    4    4
[3,]    2    5    4

[[2]] (same matrix update here)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]    5    5

[[3]]
        [,1]
[1,] 8745
[2,] 8745454
[3,] 87
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  What do you mean by new row?  From the objects created, only `q` can add a row.  If you want to create another object append to `g` either `g[[4]] <- s` where `s` is a new object or use `append`

Comment: We can use `Map` i.e. `Map(rbind, g, g1)`

Comment: Instead of `p1`, `q1`, `r1`, please show the exact output you want

Comment: That is the output I also get by `rbind`ing.  So, what do you expect to happen when `rbind` the same object?

Comment: I am not following what you really wanted.  You said to store these as individual rows.

Comment: @Akrun i think what you said is working but I am just confused how to update the list and do the rbind for different values.

Comment: Can you show an example  (I meant your expected output, assuming that you know what you really wanted) so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @akrun updated the post

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, `Map` should work i.e. `p <- c(1, 3, 4);
q <- matrix(c(1, 2, 4, 5), nrow=2, ncol=2);
r <- 8745;

p2 <- c(1, 4, 4);
q2 <- matrix(c(5, 5, 4, 6), nrow=2, ncol=2);
r2 <- 8745454;

p3 <- c(2, 5, 4);
q3 <- matrix(c(1, 3, 3, 6), nrow=2, ncol=2);
r3 <- 87;

Map(rbind, list(p, q, r), list(p2, q2, r2), list(p3, q3, r3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following to get this working,

```
Somelist <- list()
Somelist[[length(Somelist)+1]] <- list(p, q, r)
```